# React router - Specify routes interface

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have a question with React router, I need specify values to my routes, example:

I've the route path: `'/step/:step'`, the parameter `':step'` should only receive numbers between 1 and 4

But the route receive any numbers, How to add a middleware or route validation without putting code directly in the component

Thanks!

Comment: react-router does not provide any such middleware, you have to check that in the component itself!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Route`'s [`path` prop](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/path-string-string) actually accepts regex, so try something like `path="/step/:step(1|2|3|4)"`. It is parsed with [path-to-regexp](https://github.com/pillarjs/path-to-regexp/tree/v1.7.0) library.

If provided URL does not match the rule, Router will skip this route, so there is no need for additional middleware or additional check in the underlying component.

Answer (score 1):

Route receives everything as user can type it manually in the browser. If it is not between 1 and 4, you should redirect the user to 404 page.